# Scientific plot with Ruby + wxWidgets

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, plot

I need to incorporate some scientific plot function into a program written in Ruby with wxWidgets. What's my best solution? I know that

1) PLPlot has a widget for wxWigets, but I'm not aware of any ruby bindings.

2) Python works well PLPlot and wxWigets, but I rather not rewrite the whole thing in python again.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/graphing.html might help you